# Java metadata read and write

Tags: java, image, image-processing, metadata

Is it possible in a generic way (for all image types) to be able to read and write metadata in Java, i've found a few examples but they are always specific, for JPEG or PNG for example. I need something generic enough to not if else statement everywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid it is always specific. But if you want it for "internal" use in your own software, only, you could think of external storage of the metadata. But I guess that's not an option?

Comment: That's the problem:(. I would have been for use in a large-scale application, which sorts of does everything. So no metadata champs on the scene. We have gone for the option to discard this problem and continue with our lives. Thanks anyway. xoxo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to rewrite the source but here is an great example

http://johnbokma.com/java/obtaining-image-metadata.html

Look at the readandDisplayMetaData function and it will give you an idea.

Comment: We decided against keeping the meta-data now, it was originally used for when photos orientation data was wrong, and the image was displayed sideways, but then we give the option for them to manually correct the orientation, which just then strips the meta-data, as we found it has no more use.

But thanks for the response, an actual bit of code to take into consideration.

I no-doubt have to stare down metadata again in the near future. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every file format has a different way of storing metadata. Asking for a generic way to read and write metadata is like asking for a generic way to read and write all file formats.

Comment: Fine. Write your universal metadata generator, and you'll get rich.

Comment: Your right, it most definitely has a different way of storing metadata, this question was a shot in the dark. But your example was bad. Reading metadata as keys/values which could be extracted, whereas file formats can be wildly different.