# how to update the value of metadata for jpg ,tiff files in JAVA?

Tags: java, metadata

i want to update the metadata (like tag,comments etc.....) of .jpg & .tif files using JAVA 
can any one help me with example  ....

i have done same for docx file using apache poi

```
      OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open("metadata.docx");
      PackageProperties pp = opc.getPackageProperties();

      Nullable<String> foo = pp.getLastModifiedByProperty();
      System.out.println(foo.hasValue()?foo.getValue():"empty");
      //Set some properties
      pp.setCreatorProperty("M Kazarian");
      pp.setLastModifiedByProperty("M Kazarian " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      pp.setModifiedProperty(new Nullable<Date>(new Date()));
      pp.setTitleProperty("M Kazarian document");
```

note:then plz mention the jar that i should download & import to update the metadata .

thanks in advance ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java metadata read and write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895251/java-metadata-read-and-write)

Comment: actually i want to update the value of the metadata

Comment: Updating means reading and writing, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [commons imaging](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/)

[Here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/examples/WriteExifMetadataExample.java) is the example of how to update JPEG metadata:

```
public void changeExifMetadata(final File jpegImageFile, final File dst)
        throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException {
    OutputStream os = null;
    boolean canThrow = false;
    try {
        TiffOutputSet outputSet = null;

        final IImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(jpegImageFile);
        final JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
        if (null != jpegMetadata) {
            final TiffImageMetadata exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();

            if (null != exif) {
                outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
            }
        }

        if (null == outputSet) {
            outputSet = new TiffOutputSet();
        }

        {
            final TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet
                    .getOrCreateExifDirectory();
            exifDirectory
                    .removeField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE);
            exifDirectory.add(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE,
                    RationalNumber.factoryMethod(3, 10));
        }

        {
            final double longitude = -74.0; 
            final double latitude = 40 + 43 / 60.0; 

            outputSet.setGPSInDegrees(longitude, latitude);
        }

        os = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

        new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossless(jpegImageFile, os,
                outputSet);

        canThrow = true;
    } finally {
        IoUtils.closeQuietly(canThrow, os);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javax.imageio.metadata contains metadata related classes.  IIOMetadata class is useful for you.Try the

```
write(IIOMetadata streamMetadata,IIOImage image,ImageWriteParam param)
```

method in ImageWriter class.